# Encode formatting information into a Google Sheets or Excel formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using an Excel document opened in Google Sheets. I understand that either Google Sheets syntax or Excel syntax may therefore be used, so either style would be useful to me here.

I'm have a cell which compares two durations.

**For example:**

> Cell 1 = 01:05
>   Cell 2 = 01:15
>   Cell 3 = 00:10 [RED]

If Cell 2's duration is greater than cell 1's then cell 3 should be colored red. If not, then green.

I can't do this using conditional formatting because the cell 3 is always a positive number, so I have to following formula to compute cell 3 (which is placed in cell 3:

```
=IF(C2 > C1, [RED]C2 - C1, [GREEN]C1 - C2)
```

The above is producing the correct values with the colors removed, but but the can't find away to 
implement the red and green successfully. If the colors are included it gives a parsing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the fill colour of C3 to green then in conditional formatting for C3 use custom formula:

```
=C2>C1
```

with fill colour red.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Not quite what I was after, but a suitable workaround until I can find how to do this. I really want to be able to copy the formatting with the formula, so I don't need to set up conditional formatting rules, everywhere it is used!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. The conditional formatting does copy with the formula if using copy & paste - it will always refer to the two cells immediately above the current cell.